# How to desconsider row for statistical operation that contains NA in specific column in R?

Tags: r

I want to execute Shapiro test for the following data frame (example) but I think the NA value in row 5 could change the result. How can I disregard the row for the analysis without excluding the row containing the NA value?

| id | subject | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | control | 0.151708 |
| 2 | control | 0.239930 |
| 3 | patient | 0.104289 |
| 4 | patient | 0.329139 |
| 5 | patient | NA |

Would be nice if the Shapiro function accepted 'na.rm' or 'na.omit' as argument. However, it doesn't work.

```
byf.shapiro(dados_novo$measurement ~ dados_novo$subject, dados_novo, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Try something like `byf.shapiro(dados_novo$measurement ~ dados_novo$subject, dados_novo[!is.na(dados_novo$measurement), ])`?

Comment: Same result as ```byf.shapiro(dados_novo$measurement ~ dados_novo$subject, dados_novo)```

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: The result considers the NA value, or exclude from the analysis the row 5 automatically?

Comment: The results do not consider `NA` values when implementing the code from my comment, and if those results are the same as your attempt, your attempt also exclude the `NA` values